# nginx location alias to root dir with another index file

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, virtualhost

i have 2 index file in root dir (index.php, thanks.php) and want to use thanks.php when user request other location, for ex:
when user request **example.com** nginx show **index.php**,but when user request **example.com/thanks** nginx must show **thanks.php**
i tryed this config, but it's not working for me:

```
server {
root /var/www/example.com;    
    index index.php;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location /thanks {
        alias /var/www/example.com;
        index thanks.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a missing `;` should be `index thanks.php;` - is this in the actual server configuration file?

Comment: fixed, but still not works

Comment: alias doesn't work this way. Please check the docs at https://nginx.org/r/alias. You must be getting 301 for example.com/thanks. Instead of using a location block, I'd suggest `rewrite ^/thanks$ /thanks.php;`, if you are going to serve only one URL with thanks.php file.